# Read excel file in python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read excel file in pycharm using pandas. I installed the package successfully. My issue is that I am trying to use file location in addition to its name I tried many thing as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\GTS\\Desktop\\Network Interdiction Problem\\Manuscript\\Interdiction_Data.xlsx"
fileName = 'Interdiction_Data.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel('fileLocation'+'fileName')
```

However I keep receiving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GTS/PycharmProjects/Reliability1/Reliability1.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel('fileLocation'+'fileName')
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Reliability1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Reliability1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Reliability1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Reliability1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Reliability1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\GTS\PycharmProjects\Reliability1\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fileLocationfileName'
```

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know the difference between a variable and a str? try : `pd.read_excel(fileLocation)`

Comment: That's work Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fileLocation` variable includes the name of the file. reading `fileLocation + fileName` is essentially reading

`C:\\Users\\GTS\\Desktop\\Network Interdiction Problem\\Manuscript\\Interdiction_Data.xlsxInterdiction_Data.xlsx`

Another issue is that you have quotation marks around your variable names when calling `pd.read_excel()` meaning that you are passing a string to the function.

Try:

```
data = pd.read_excel(fileLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing some issues in your code...
First, let's start with the pd.read_excel() documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

It says there if the file is saved in your current working directory, just pass the file name to your function.

```
import pandas as pd
fileName = 'Interdiction_Data.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(fileName) # notice that when we call an object, we didn't use quotation marks.
```

However, if your file is not in your current directory, just pass the path to the file or as you called "filelocation".

```
import pandas as pd
fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\GTS\\Desktop\\Network Interdiction Problem\\Manuscript\\Interdiction_Data.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(fileLocation) # notice that when we call an object, we didn't use quotation marks.
```

Tip: To avoid some bugs or issues with file paths or directory names, try not to use space so separate the words...

I hope you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl` is a Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm/xltx/xltm files.

Install it like this

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Example code

```
df = pd.read_excel('File_name.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).